# Default file transfer mode in SCP

Tags: scp

I want to know what is the default mode used (ASCII or binary like FTP) while transferring files using SCP.

Is there any file mode concept in SCP ? How does it work ?

Answer (score 40):

The file transfer modes in FTP are used to solve the problem of different operating systems having different line endings. The idea is that if a text file is transferred from a Unix machine to a Windows machine, the line endings must fixed, meaning that LF must be replaced by CR LF everywhere in the file. The reverse operation must be done when transferring the file in the other direction.

However, if you're transferring binary files, you want to leave the file as-is, because any LFs in the binary file are not actually line endings. Therefore, FTP introduced ASCII mode and Binary mode.

This is still a problematic solution, especially because the default mode is ASCII mode, so if you forgot to switch modes you might mangle your binary files and they won't work. The different modes are considered to cause more trouble than the problem they solve.

And so, SCP simply does not provide this feature, and always leaves the files as is. Fixing line endings is left to the user using tools like `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`.

In essence, all files are transferred in "binary" mode, meaning that line endings are never changed.

Answer (score 6):

According to my knowledge there is no mode for scp.
See this [man](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/scp.1.asp) page for more details

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know what is the default mode used (ASCII or binary like FTP) while transferring files using SCP.

Unfortunately, in my experience, it depends a bit on the implementation of scp on the OS you are running on.  For example, although linux scp doesn't seem to do make any changes to the files -- i.e. EOL characters are not converted between Windows and linux, this is not true under z/OS (sic).  On the IBM mainframe, all files being scp-ed seem to be converted from ASCII to EBCDIC character encoding by the scp application itself.

However, it looks like sftp by default does *not* do the character converting so files come over in their native ASCII.